How to enable keymap for Lazygit?
I am trying to enable a keymap for Lazygit. I have added the following into my tmux.conf:
set -g @plugin 'kdheepak/lazygit.nvim'

And have added the following to my keymaps.lua:
-- Keymap for launching Lazygit by hitting space+gg
vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>gg', ':LazyGit<CR>')

However, I get a pop-up saying LazyGit isn't an available command. If I open a terminal and simply run the Lazygit command, it does open Lazygit.

I know I am missing something, I just don't know what. I am using this guy's pre-built configuration for Tmux, Nvim and so on: https://github.com/omerxx/dotfiles
I don't want to be spoon-fed necessarily, but if someone could take a peek at the github repository, and tell me what I need to add where. I am very new to Nvim and all of that ecosystem, learning by troubleshooting, but I've been breaking my head over this the past few hours.
Thank you all.

If using Lazygit plugin:
You would put this in your nvim/lua/plugins/lazy.lua file since your package manager is Lazy.
# nvim/lua/plugins/lazy.lua

require("lazy").setup({
    -- Rest of your requirements...
    {
        "kdheepak/lazygit.nvim",
        cmd = {
            "LazyGit",
            "LazyGitConfig",
            "LazyGitCurrentFile",
            "LazyGitFilter",
            "LazyGitFilterCurrentFile",
        },
        -- optional for floating window border decoration
        dependencies = {
            "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
        },
        -- setting the keybinding for LazyGit with 'keys' is recommended in
        -- order to load the plugin when the command is run for the first time
        keys = {
           { "<leader>lg", "<cmd>LazyGit<cr>", desc = "LazyGit" }
        }
    },
    -- Rest of your requirements...
})

Run :Lazy install at the end.
If using Lazygit installed separately on the system:
Running :terminal lazygit will open up Lazygit for you.
vim.keymap.set('n', '<space>gg', ':terminal lazygit<CR>')

Or in my personal config I run it on Togglterm in a floating/split terminal.
local Terminal = require("toggleterm.terminal").Terminal

-- Lazygit
local lazygit = Terminal:new({
    cmd = "lazygit",
    hidden = true,
    direction = "float",
    close_on_exit = true,
})

function _LAZYGIT_TOGGLE()
    lazygit:toggle()
end

keymap("n", "<leader>tg", "<cmd>lua _LAZYGIT_TOGGLE()<CR>", opts)


Thanks for replying @dkasa, when I do :Lazy install, , I do not see lazygit mentioned there, did I do something incorrectly? I created a new file in the plugins folder called lazygit.lua and pasted the first code snippet there. I chose the first method you suggested which seemed easier. Lazygit does not open when I hit space lg. Appreciate your help really.

@Assaf Sorry made a mistake with the instructions. Made an edit to the answer. Reload Neovim after you make the changes as well.

Thank you @dkasa. I am still struggling, I edited according to your new instructions using the first method of editing the lazy.lua and there are 2 issues:

I have to to :Lazy load lazygit in order for the keymap to work.
Even when I do that and Lazygit opens, it doesn't recognize the repository I am in while navigating Nvim.
Appreciate your kind help.


@Assaf Adding lazy = false into the configuration you added to the plugins/lazy.lua file in order to automatically load the plugin and if you want to open the current buffers repo use :LazyGitCurrentFile instead of the basic :LazyGit command in your config.
